# Web scraping a website with dynamic javascript content

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So I'm using python and beautifulsoup4(which i'm not tied to) to scrape a website. Problem is when I use urlib to grab the html of a page it's not the entire page because some of it is generated via the javascript. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tried Python BeautifulSoup and Phantom JS: STILL can't scrape websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028775/tried-python-beautifulsoup-and-phantom-js-still-cant-scrape-websites)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are basically two main options to proceed with:

- using browser developer tools, see what ajax requests are going to load the page and simulate them in your script, you will probably need to use [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to load the response json string into python data structure
- use tools like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) that open up a real browser. The browser can also be "headless", see [Headless Selenium Testing with Python and PhantomJS](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.UzWCza1dXQg)

The first option is more difficult to implement and it's, generally speaking, more fragile, but it doesn't require a real browser and can be faster.

The second option is better in terms of you get what any other real user gets and you wouldn't be worried about how the page was loaded. Selenium is pretty powerful in [locating elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) on a page - you may not need `BeautifulSoup` at all. But, anyway, this option is slower than the first one.

Hope that helps.