# python requests & beautifulsoup bot detection

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all the HTML elements of a page using requests & beautifulsoup. I'm using ASIN (Amazon Standard Identification Number) to get the product details of a page. My code is as follows:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/" + 'B004CNH98C'
response = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

But the [output](https://codepen.io/proteeti/pen/qMaZzN?editors=1000) doesn't show the entire HTML of the page, so I can't do my further work with product details. 
Any help on this?

EDIT 1:

From the given answer, It shows the markup of the bot detection page. I researched a bit & found two ways to breach it :

1. I might need to add a header in the requests, but I couldn't understand what should be the value of header.
2. Use Selenium.
   Now my question is, do both of the ways provide equal support?

Comment: It'd be nice if you can give out what B004CNH98C is supposed to be so people can look at the actual page. My guess is that some of the html stuff are hidden under javascript functions. You should load the page on to Selenium and click it.

Comment: meanwhile I just got acquainted with selenium webdriver. Is a new chrome window going to open everytime  when I try to scrape for each page?

Comment: Use headless options.

Comment: pages that use javascript frameworks cannot be scraped wtih BS. And why scrape when amazon has such a nice API??

Comment: I don't think Amazon API is supported in my country

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web scraping a website with dynamic javascript content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715036/web-scraping-a-website-with-dynamic-javascript-content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some of the comments already suggested, if you need to somehow interact with Javascript on a page, it is better to use selenium. However, regarding your first approach using a header:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/" + 'B004CNH98C'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
```

These headers are a bit old, but should still work. By using them you are pretending that your request is coming from a normal webbrowser. If you use `requests` without such a header your code is basically telling the server that the request is coming from python, which most of the servers are rejecting right away.

Another alternative for you could also be [fake-useragent](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) maybe you can also have a try with this.

Comment: I was confused if  'User-Agent' takes any predefined format to give my machine information. I came across this  https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_type_specific/web-browser/. I guess this will be header I pass, am I correct?

Comment: Also from the docs, it says that custom made headers are given less precendence.  Does it mean "less precedence" in terms of accepting the requests?

Comment: From the list of browsers you posted you can select the header you want to use. Your request is then pretending to come from this browser. I haven't found the passage about "less precedence" so I can only assume what is meant, but in general the servers are mostly rejecting requests which look in some way automated in order to keep a good performance. This is why it is necessary to pretend to be a real browser so that the server is accepting your request.

Comment: However these days most websites are providing APIs for people who want to use automated requests. This is actually good for both parties. API requests are better for server performance and also for you less code is necessary and it is much more straightforward. So in general I can recommend to check if a page is providing an API, before trying to parse it the "hacky" way.

Answer (score 9):

It is better to use fake_useragent here for making things easy. A random user agent sends request via real world browser usage statistic. If you don't need dynamic content, you're almost always better off just requesting the page content over HTTP  and parsing it programmatically.

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
ua=UserAgent()
hdr = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/" + 'B004CNH98C'
response = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
print response.content
```

Selenium is used for browser automation and high level web scraping for dynamic contents.

Comment: TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/" + 'B004CNH98C'
r = requests.get(url)
r = r.text

##options #1
#  print r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup( r.encode("utf-8") , "html.parser")

### options 2
print(soup)
```

Comment: Already tried this way, leads to the "make sure you are not a robot" page.