# This code for Web Scraping using python returning None. Why? Any help would be appreciated

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

headers = {'Use-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Alpha-a6400-Mirrorless-Camera/dp/B07MV3P7M8/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=sony+alpha&qid=1581656953&s=electronics&sr=1-4'

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()

price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

print(title)

print(price)
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? What specifically is the issue?

Comment: I did no debugging. It is returning None at line `soup.find(id="productTitle")`

Comment: _I did no debugging._ https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine but there is a robot check before the product page so your request looks for the span tag in that robot check page, fails and returns `None`.

Here is a link which may help you: [python requests & beautifulsoup bot detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068920/python-requests-beautifulsoup-bot-detection)