# Python Requests only pulling half of intented tags

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm attempting to scrape a website, and pull each sheriff's name and county. I'm using devtools in chrome to identify the HTML tag needed to locate that information.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://oregonsheriffs.org/about-ossa/meet-your-sheriffs'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

sheriff_names = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'eg-sheriff-list-skin-element-1')
sheriff_counties = soup.find_all(class_ = 'eg-sheriff-list-skin-element-2')
```

However, I'm finding that Requests is *not* pulling the entire page's html, even though the  tag is at the end. If I scan `page.content`, I find that Sheriff Harrold is the last sheriff included, and that every sheriff from curtis landers onwards is not included (I tried pasting the full output of `page.contents` but it's too long).

My best guess from reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416507/python-requests-not-getting-full-page) is that the website has javascripts that load the remaining part of the page upon interacting with it, which would imply that I need to use something like Selenium to interact with the page to get the rest of it to first load.

However, if you look at the website, it's very simple, so as a novice part of me is thinking that there has to be a way to scrape this basic website without using a more complex tool like Selenium. That said, I recognize that the website is wordpress generated and wordpress can set up delayed javascripts on even simple web sites.

My questions are: 
1) do I really need to use Selenium to scrape a simple, word-press generated website like this? Or is there a way to get the full page to load with just Requests? Is there anyway to tell when web pages will require a web driver and when Requests will not be enough? 
2) I'm thinking one step ahead here - if I want to scale up this project, how would I be able to tell that Requests has not returned the full website, without manually inspecting the results of every website?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding user agent, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652558/4985099

Comment: Thanks! Based on that link, I tried the following:


header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}

Then I passed header to requests.get:

page = requests.get(URL, headers = header)

Same problem though - not picking up the bottom half of the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your initial instinct is almost certainly correct. If you look at the page source it seems that they have some sort of lazy loading going on, pulling content from an external source.

A quick look at the page source indicates that they're probably using the "Essential Grid" WordPress theme to do this. I think this supports preloading. If you look at the requests that are made you might be able to ascertain how it's loading this and pull directly from that source (perhaps a REST call, AJAX, etc).

In a generalized sense, I'm afraid that there really isn't any automated way to programmatically determine if a page has 'fully' loaded, as that behavior is defined in code and can be triggered by anything.

If you want to capture information from pages that load content as you scroll, though, I believe Selenium is the tool you'll have to use.