# How to wait to page to fully load using requests_html

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

While accessing this link **https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/tents-accessories?pageNumber=2** with requests_html, i need to wait to wait some time before the page actually loads. Is it possible with this?
My code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

s = HTMLSession()
response = s.get(
    'https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/f/tents-accessories?pageNumber=2')
response.html.render()


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
item = dom.xpath('//a[@class="rs_product_description d-block"]/text()')[0]
print(item)
```

Comment: Already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416507/python-requests-not-getting-full-page

Comment: That answer says to use "r.html.render()"  and I am already doing that.

Comment: @Ibstam Ch pip install requests-html

from requests_html import HTMLSession
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

Comment: I don’t think you’ve added the requests-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data you are looking for can be fetched using **HTTP GET** to
https://prod-catalog-product-api.dickssportinggoods.com/v2/search?searchVO=%7B%22selectedCategory%22%3A%2212301_1809051%22%2C%22selectedStore%22%3A%220%22%2C%22selectedSort%22%3A1%2C%22selectedFilters%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22storeId%22%3A15108%2C%22pageNumber%22%3A2%2C%22pageSize%22%3A48%2C%22totalCount%22%3A112%2C%22searchTypes%22%3A%5B%22PINNING%22%5D%2C%22isFamilyPage%22%3Atrue%2C%22appliedSeoFilters%22%3Afalse%2C%22snbAudience%22%3A%22%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%22%22%7D

The call will return a JSON and you can use that direcly with zero scraping code.

Copy/Paste the URL into the browser --> see the data.

You **can specify** the page number in the url:

```
searchVO={"selectedCategory":"12301_1809051","selectedStore":"0","selectedSort":1,"selectedFilters":{},"storeId":15108,"pageNumber":2,"pageSize":48,"totalCount":112,"searchTypes":["PINNING"],"isFamilyPage":true,"appliedSeoFilters":false,"snbAudience":"","zipcode":""}
```

***working code below***

```
import requests
import pprint

page_num = 2
url = f'https://prod-catalog-product-api.dickssportinggoods.com/v2/search?searchVO=%7B%22selectedCategory%22%3A%2212301_1809051%22%2C%22selectedStore%22%3A%220%22%2C%22selectedSort%22%3A1%2C%22selectedFilters%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22storeId%22%3A15108%2C%22pageNumber%22%3A2%2C%2{page_num}pageSize%22%3A48%2C%22totalCount%22%3A112%2C%22searchTypes%22%3A%5B%22PINNING%22%5D%2C%22isFamilyPage%22%3Atrue%2C%22appliedSeoFilters%22%3Afalse%2C%22snbAudience%22%3A%22%22%2C%22zipcode%22%3A%22%22%7D'

r = requests.get(url)
if r.status_code == 200:
    pprint.pprint(r.json())
```

Comment: Yes but In this request I cant specify page number

Comment: @IbtsamCh - the answer was updated with working code that lets you specify the page number. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Hey sorry but I want to change the select category too for categories available on https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/c/camping-hiking-gear. Is there any way to find those category numbers? I cant find them anywhere

Comment: Look at `searchVO` dict in my answer. There you can find the available arguments.

Comment: Yes we can change it definitely but I cant find the category numbers for other categories anywehre except the api url like this category has "selectedCategory":"12301_1809051". this value is change for other categories

Comment: So your question is "how do I know other cat. ids?" - if the answer is yes here is what you should do. Browse the website and "play" with other cat. At the same time use dev tools (F12)  -> Netwoek -> XHR and look for the HTTP request that starts with `https://prod-catalog-product-api.dickssportinggoods.com/v2/search` - there you will find it.

Comment: yes I can find that way definitely. but i wanted to automate it instead of finding the cat ids for every category

Comment: why dont you prepare a dict that looks like: `{'cat1': 12,'cat6':234}` and use it in run time? (12.& 234 are the ids in  this example)

Comment: sadly this only answer a specific web the op facing

Answer (score 0):

You can induce `Selenium` as well in `headless mode.`

`Selenium` has the capability to `wait unit elements are found with Explicit waits.`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
driver.get("URL here")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='rs_product_description d-block']")))
```

**PS:** You'd have to download chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

Comment: yes but I want to avoid selenium. isn't there any other way?

Comment: What is the reason you do not wanna use Selenium ?

Comment: because its slow and  inconsistent too. Many a times it would be working fine but as soon I add headless argument it stops working.

Comment: selenium is just bad. op is right. it's heavy, especially if you want to perform a simple task. why force people to use selenium? its un-deployable and problematic