# Using beautifulsoup4, avoid an AttributeError on a non-existing element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good time of the day!

While working on a scraping project, I have faced some issues.
Currently I am working on a draft:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time 
import random 
#driver Path
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver"

BASE_URL = "https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/house/for-sale/ottignies/1340/9308167"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(BASE_URL)
time.sleep(random.uniform(3.0, 5.0))

btn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]')[0]
btn.click()
r = requests.get(BASE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

def reader(url):
    ls = list()
    ImmoWebCode = url.find(class_ ="classified__information--immoweb-code").text.strip()     
    Price = url.find("p", class_="classified__price").find("span",class_="sr-only").text.strip()
    Locality = url.find(class_="classified__information--address-row").find("span").text.strip()
    HouseType = url.find(class_="classified__title").text.strip()
    LivingArea = url.find("th",text="Living area").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    RoomsNumber = url.find("th",text="Bedrooms").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    Kitchen = url.find("th",text="Kitchen type").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    TerraceOrientation = url.find("th",text="Terrace orientation").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    TerraceArea = url.find("th",text="Terrace").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    Furnished = url.find("th",text="Furnished").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    ls.append(Furnished)
    OpenFire = url.find("th", text="How many fireplaces?").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    GardenOrientation = url.find("th", text="Garden orientation").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    ls.append(GardenOrientation)
    GardenArea = url.find("th",text="Garden surface").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    PlotSurface = url.find("th",text="Surface of the plot").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    ls.append(PlotSurface)
    FacadeNumber = url.find("th",text="Number of frontages").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    SwimmingPoool = url.find("th",text="Swimming pool").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    StateOfTheBuilding = url.find("th",text="Building condition").find_next(class_="classified-table__data").next_element.strip()
    return ls

print(reader(soup))
```

I start facing issues, when the code reaches "Locality", I receive an `Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find`, though it is clear that the mentioned element is present on HTML code. I am adamant, that it is a synthax issue, but I can not put a finger on it.

It brings me to my second question:
Since this code will be running on multiple pages, those pages might not have requested elements. How can I place the `None` value if it occurs.

Thank you very much in advance!

Source Code:

```
<div class="classified__header-secondary-info classified__informations"><p class="classified__information--property">
    3 bedrooms
        <span aria-hidden="true">|</span>
        199
<span class="abbreviation"><span aria-hidden="true">
m²                                    </span> <span class="sr-only">
square meters                                    </span></span></p> <div class="classified__information--financial"><!----> <a href="https://www.immoweb.be/en/credit-application?classified=9308167&amp;icid_to=mortgage&amp;icid_cta=classified-header" class="classified__information--mortgage-banner small"><!----> <span class="mortgage-banner__text">Request your mortgage loan</span></a></div> <div class="classified__information--address"><p><span class="classified__information--address-row"><span>
1340
</span> <span aria-hidden="true">—</span> <span>
Ottignies
</span>
|
</span> <button class="button button--text button--size-small classified__information--address-button">
Ask for the exact address
</button></p></div> <div class="classified__information--immoweb-code">
Immoweb code : 9308167
</div></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the part of the source code from which you're trying to extract the data? Your code looks and works fine as long as an element with the class `classified__information--address-row` exists and that element contains a `span` tag.

Comment: It is quiet confusing, as while I inspect the page, I can see the elements I want to pick, though I can not find them on the source code..

Comment: This sounds like the elements are dynamically added to the page using Javascript. Look at this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22715113

Comment: I have just figured this out, thanks! I will use selenium, it appears to work!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that data all within the `<table>` tags of the site? Can just use pandas:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/house/for-sale/ottignies/1340/9308167'
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)

df = pd.concat(dfs).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.pivot(index=None, columns=0,values=1).bfill().iloc[[0],:]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
0                            Address As built plan Available as of               Available date Basement Bathrooms Bedrooms   CO₂ emission Construction year Double glazing Elevator   Energy class External reference Furnished Garden Garden orientation Gas, water & electricity Heating type Investment property Kitchen type Land is facing street            Living area   Living room surface Number of frontages Outdoor parking spaces                Price Primary energy consumption Reference number of the EPC report Shower rooms     Surface of the plot Toilets                Website Yearly theoretical total energy consumption
0  Grand' Route 69 A 1435  - Corbais            No   To be defined  December 31 2022 - 12:00 AM      Yes         1        3  Not specified              2020            Yes      Yes  Not specified        8566 - 4443        No    Yes               East                      Yes          Gas                  No    Installed                    No  199  m² square meters  48  m² square meters                   2                      1  € 410,000  410000 €              Not specified                      Not specified            1  150  m²  square meters       3  http://www.gilmont.be                               Not specified
```