# Scraping links generated by javascript

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a website, and one of the links I need to scrape appears to be generated by a small snippet of Javascript code in the page, like so:

```
 <!--
 var prefix = 'm&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:';
 var suffix = '';
 var attribs = '';
 var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
 var addy59933 = 'HR-C&#111;l&#111;gn&#101;' + '&#64;';
 addy59933 = addy59933 + 'sc&#111;r' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m';
 var addy_text59933 = 'Submit your application';
 document.write( '<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + addy59933 + suffix + '\'' + attribs + '>' );
 document.write( addy_text59933 );
 document.write( '<\/a>' );
 //-->
```

The link won't show up unless you view the page from a browser, but I need my spider to be able to scrape it anyways. Since the code is embedded within the page, I had the idea to grab the  and then re-assemble the link url from there, but the text is in a format I'm not familiar with.

Is there a better way to do it?

edit: Just figured out that those are HTML Character Entities. I'd still like to know if there are better ways to overcome this sort of obfuscation.

Comment: Scrapy cannot handle the case. You need smth to run this js code and generate a link. One option is to use a real-browser-based tool, like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). You can actually start it from your spider, get the link and then close the browser. But, I'm pretty sure, this would slow things down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tried Python BeautifulSoup and Phantom JS: STILL can't scrape websites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028775/tried-python-beautifulsoup-and-phantom-js-still-cant-scrape-websites)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [js2xml](https://github.com/redapple/js2xml):

```
>>> import js2xml
>>> import pprint
>>> jscode = r"""
... var prefix = 'm&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:';
... var suffix = '';
... var attribs = '';
... var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
... var addy59933 = 'HR-C&#111;l&#111;gn&#101;' + '&#64;';
... addy59933 = addy59933 + 'sc&#111;r' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m';
... var addy_text59933 = 'Submit your application';
... document.write( '<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + addy59933 + suffix + '\'' + attribs + '>' );
... document.write( addy_text59933 );
... document.write( '<\/a>' );
>>> js = js2xml.parse(jscode)
```

Variable declarations are represented by `var_decl` elements, their name is in `identifier` node and their values here are strings, with `+` operator, so let's make a `dict` out of them, using `"".join()` on `string/text()` elements:

```
>>> # variables
... variables = dict([(var.xpath('string(./identifier)'), u"".join(var.xpath('.//string/text()')))
...                   for var in js.xpath('.//var_decl')])
>>> pprint.pprint(variables)
{'addy59933': u'HR-C&#111;l&#111;gn&#101;&#64;',
 'addy_text59933': u'Submit your application',
 'attribs': u'',
 'path': u'href=',
 'prefix': u'm&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:',
 'suffix': u''}
```

Then assignments change values of some variables, with a mix of strings and variables. Concatenate `%(identifidername)s` for variable identifiers and strings values for strings

```
>>> # identifiers are assigned other string values
... assigns = {}
>>> for assign in js.xpath('.//assign'):
...     value = u"".join(['%%(%s)s' % el.text if el.tag=='identifier' else el.text
...                       for el in assign.xpath('./right//*[self::string or self::identifier]')])
...     key = assign.xpath('string(left/identifier)')
...     assigns[key] = value
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(assigns)
{'addy59933': u'%(addy59933)ssc&#111;r&#46;c&#111;m'}
```

Update the variables dict "applying" the assignements

```
>>> # update variables dict with new values
... for key, val in assigns.items():
...    variables[key] = val % variables
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(variables)
{'addy59933': u'HR-C&#111;l&#111;gn&#101;&#64;sc&#111;r&#46;c&#111;m',
 'addy_text59933': u'Submit your application',
 'attribs': u'',
 'path': u'href=',
 'prefix': u'm&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:',
 'suffix': u''}
>>>
```

Function arguments are under `arguments` node (XPath `.//arguments/*`):

```
>>> # interpret arguments of document.write()
... arguments = [u"".join(['%%(%s)s' % el.text if el.tag=='identifier' else el.text
...                        for el in arg.xpath('./descendant-or-self::*[self::string or self::identifier]')])
...              for arg in js.xpath('.//arguments/*')]
>>> 
>>> pprint.pprint(arguments)
[u"<a %(path)s'%(prefix)s%(addy59933)s%(suffix)s'%(attribs)s>",
 u'%(addy_text59933)s',
 u'</a>']
>>>
```

If you replace the identifiers in there, you get

```
>>> # apply string formatting replacing identifiers
... arguments = [arg % variables for arg in arguments]
>>> 
>>> pprint.pprint(arguments)
[u"<a href='m&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:HR-C&#111;l&#111;gn&#101;&#64;sc&#111;r&#46;c&#111;m'>",
 u'Submit your application',
 u'</a>']
>>>
```

Now that looks interesting by let's run it through `lxml.html` to get rid of the numeric character references:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> 
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring("".join(arguments))
>>> print lxml.etree.tostring(doc)
<a href="mailto:HR-Cologne@scor.com">Submit your application</a>
>>>
```

Using Scrapy `Selector`:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> selector = Selector(text="".join(arguments), type="html")
>>> selector.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
[u'mailto:HR-Cologne@scor.com']
>>>
```

Comment: It would work only for this particular obfuscation, but, anyway, it is a very nice solution!

Comment: indeed @alecxe , I'm hoping to build some simple and basic interpretation for Javascript code into js2xml (contributions welcome!), and the XML schema is not that satisfying yet. But fetching strings or objects and arrays (via `js2xml.jsonlike.getall()`) is possible already and useful. But yeah, it won't replace a Javascript interpreter