# Web scraping cnbc.com

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape [this page](http://www.cnbc.com/pre-markets/) with bs4 and I was wondering how can I scrape the `EUR/USD`, `price change`, and `price %` ?

I am pretty new to this, so this is all I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.cnbc.com/pre-markets/'
source_code = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, 'lxml')

for r in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'first text'}):
    print(r)
```

Comment: What's the question? Is something not working as expected so that you can't continue, or are you asking us to write your actual code for you?

Comment: I think you need use requests.get(url, stream=True) and analyse code after. Look at [Bodycontent workflow](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow)

Comment: I guess my question is - is it possible to do? Looking thru the source code, it seems that the price, price change and % change are images? I could be (and probably am) completely wrong

Comment: @MadPhysicist after pulling the entire text from cnbc.com/pre-markets I noticed that the information (EUR/USD) does not show up - don't think it's possible to scrape..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you're looking for are probably loaded with javaScript and therefore you can't see them with bs4. But you can do it using an headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), Selenium or [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash). See also this response: [scraping dynamic updates of temperature sensor data from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028829/scraping-dynamic-updates-of-temperature-sensor-data-from-a-website/32031550#32031550)