# Beautiful Soup not displaying span class within div tag

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am unable to scrap the span class using beautifulsoup

```
<div class="team-1-name">
           " 
                  India
                            "

                <span class="innings-1-score innings-current">120/1 (40.0 ov)</span>

        </div>
```

soup.prettify() is not even showing the span class.

```
print(soup2.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<div class="team-2-name">
     India
    </div>


team1_soup=soup2.find(class_="team-1-name")
print(team1_soup.find("span"))
None
```

Please Help

Comment: post the url.....

Comment: URL : http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/1062575.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you try to scrape add the tag `<span class="innings-1-score innings-current">` using JavaScript (http://www.espncricinfo.com/navigation/cricinfo/ci/scorecard/js/min/templates.js?1453894715). You have also to use an headless browser like Selenium, PhantomJS or Splash to see it.
See for example: [scraping dynamic updates of temperature sensor data from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028829/scraping-dynamic-updates-of-temperature-sensor-data-from-a-website/32031550#32031550)